# Looking for the right naming of "big navigation" and also some demo examples with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I've seen a nice navigation example on http://starbucks.com/ - how is this navigation type (I call it big navigation at the moment) called?

Can you give me some other examples and maybe some tutorials to build up one - would be cool if the tutorial includes jQuery.

Thx.

Comment: @Starx, but it can be a challenge if you don't know the terms to search for. And why not ask the question here? If nothing else it increases traffic in future and helps SO become the repository of all knowledge. This is a good thing, surely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's call Mega Drop Down Menu. Quick google can get you tons of samples/tutorials like [this one](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/).

Comment: +1, beat me to it .. would suggest the same link as well.. :)